# .htaccess directory redirect to PHP argument

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have looked around and found a few examples, but they all cause:

> 500 internal server error

...so here's what I want to do:

I have a file called **view.php** in my root directory, I want it so if someone types `www.test.com/view/16` it actually displays `www.test.com/view.php?p=16`. Although I don't know how to do this without causing an error.

I would provide code, but it doesn't work and when it doesn't error, it simply redirects me to the same place, it is also a lot longer that other answers I've seen, so its not a layout I want to use. If you **really** want to see it, let me know and Ill post it.

I also don't want the URL to change in the browser, so sharing is easier... any ideas?

Comment: Consider posting your code so that others may help, even if you think it does not work.  That is the point of SO after all. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^view/(\d+)/?$ view.php?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Might be a silly question, but what does DOCUMENT_ROOT mean? Is that just the root directory?

Comment: Yes root directory for your website